# How to get keys of specific fields in an object?

Tags: javascript

I need to get an array with specific key values of an object.

Assume there is this object (optional some more different keys)

```
{
    username: 'bla',
    admin: true,
    editor: true,
    user: false,
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

I only need to process the keys `admin`, `editor` and `user` and get those keys in an array, if their value is `true`. So in the example the result should be:

```
['admin', 'editor']
```

If all three keys have a `false` value, it should return an empty array.

I would do a filter first:

```
obj.filter(e => ['admin', 'editor', 'user'].indexOf(e) > -1 && !!e)
```

and then extract the keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already have the list of fields, just apply a `.filter` call on *that*:

```js
const obj = {
    username: 'bla',
    admin: true,
    editor: true,
    user: false,
    foo: 'bar'
};

const fields = ['admin', 'editor', 'user'];
const result = fields.filter(field => obj[field] === true);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get keys from object using Object.keys and apply filter for your require data. Try below code it should work for you.

```
const obj = 
  {
    username: 'bla',
    admin: true,
    editor: true,
    user: false,
    foo: 'bar'
}
const objKeys = Object.keys(obj).filter(item => (obj[item] && typeof obj[item] == "boolean"));
```

get only keys:-

```
console.log(objKeys)
```

get array of object with key value:-

```
console.log(objKeys.map(item => ({[item] : obj[item]})))
```

Comment: `obj[item] && typeof obj[item] == "boolean"` is effectively `obj[item] === true`.